# Normal doesn't appeared on shadow/dark area in Mobile Shader

Tags: unity, android, shaders, lighting, normal-mapping

Let's look at this picture:

[image]

You can see the red rectangles, those are shaded by normalmap.

Here, is the same model with different light angle, there's no normal shading in dark area.

[image]

It only happens in Mobile Shader(simplified blinnphong actually). I'm targeting on Android devices, and using Mobile Shader with Normalmap. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since normals encode the facing direction of your surface, they only produce a change in lighting for directional lighting terms:

- Direct illumination from a directional, point, spot, or area light
- Indirect illumination or reflection from a light/reflection probe, directional lightmap, or skybox sample
- Fresnel edge reflection when the view direction just glances along the surface

In shadow, you're not getting any direct lighting so that's out. The standard shader includes a directional ambient term but the mobile shader appears to use a constant ambient light instead, and does not include Fresnel effects.

So, your options are:

- Use (or make) a shader that uses a directional ambient/global illumination term for some directional variation, or
- Add a secondary directional light to your scene, pointing at a different angle, to model the directional component of the ambient sky / bounce lighting. This light can be faint so it doesn't overly bias the appearance in lit areas, and non-shadow-casting so it's cheaper and reaches into every enclosed space.